# IF condition not working in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I want to run a stored procedure provided it meets an IF condition but this condition keeps failing. Its always returning false. From my database, @count_log is supposed to return 0. If I hard-code @count_log to be equal to 0, it works. This is my code below. Please what could be the problem?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `approve`(IN `userID` INT, IN `logID` INT, OUT `res` INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE count_log INT;
    declare exit handler for sqlexception
    BEGIN
        -- ERROR 
        rollback;
    END;

    declare exit handler for sqlwarning
    BEGIN
        -- warning -
        rollback;
    END;
        SET @count_log = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Logs WHERE logId = logID); 
        -- Confirm has not been treated -- 

        IF(@count_log = 0) THEN

        START transaction;
            -- Update table

        COMMIT;
        SELECT FOUND_ROWS() INTO res;
       END IF;

    END
```

If

Comment: have you tried to print the @count_log value, if yes then what it return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> ... WHERE logId = logID
> ```

That's true for every row, so as long as there is any record in `Logs`, `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Logs WHERE logId = logID)` will return a value lager than 0.

You supposedly mean to compare the column of the table with the passed parameter of the same name. Try to qualify one of them with the table name. As the parameter takes precedence that will mean the qualified one resolves to the table column, the other to the parameter.

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Logs WHERE Logs.logId = logID)
```

Or rename the parameter.

See ["C.1 Restrictions on Stored Programs"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html) for more information about the precedence:

> - A routine parameter takes precedence over a table column.

Answer (score 2):

Your parameter name is in conflict with the parameter name (as @sticky_bit describes).  Simply use better naming conventions:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `approve`(
    IN in_userID INT,
    IN in_logID INT,
    OUT out_res INT
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_count_log INT;
    . . .
    SELECT v_count_log := COUNT(*)
    FROM Logs l
    WHERE l.logId = in_logID; 

    . . .
END;
```